# Is there any way to generate only CSS source maps with webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, production, source-maps

I'm experimenting with webpack builds and interesting question occurred. I want to generate CSS only source maps for prod and when I use `devtool: "source-map",` I end up with both JS and CSS maps. I did a quick search about this "issue", but nothing came up. Is there any easy way to control which maps I generate?

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool

> Instead of using the devtool option you can also use SourceMapDevToolPlugin/EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin directly as it has more options. Never use both the devtool option and plugin together.

So drop that source-map setting on the devtool option, and install / plug in:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/

From there, SourceMapDevToolPlugin's `exclude` or `include` options is where you being to narrow down CSS only maps.

Comment: I did what you suggest and disabled `devtool`, but the result is a bit weird. When I use basic configuration `plugins: [new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({})]` no source maps are generated. When I activate `devtool` both css and js source maps are generated. When I want to exclude all .js files for example the result is opposite - I end up with only js souce map generated, but no css one. Similar issue [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5547).